# how to setup podspec to depend on other local pod

Tags: swift, frameworks, cocoapods, podspec

I have 2 frameworks implemented using swift: A and B which depends on A.
There is a podspec setup for A which works fine.

Currently I am setting up the podspec for B, by defining

```
spec.dependency  'A', '~> 0.0.1'
```

Also A pod is included in Podfile of B framework.

```
pod 'A', '~> 0.0.1'
```

After running
    `pod spec lint B.podspec --verbose`

shows the following error:

```
None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `A (~> 0.0.1)`.

You have either:

 - out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.

 - mistyped the name or version.
```

I have tried whatever was suggested, no changes.

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: do you mind to show the real code? are the pods installed with repo-update before you run the lib lint?

Comment: @AlejandroL.Rocha yes, it doesn't help.
the thing  it doesn't understand A is private pod, it looks in global cocoapods,
Shall I specify the path of private pods? where and how?